# Robospice and potentially multiple pending requests

Tags: android, robospice

I'm using RoboSpice and I'm trying to reconnect to pending requests upon rotation. I'm doing most of the RoboSpice work in a fragment. I'm trying to figure out how to detect which pending request got connected.

Here's my scenario. I have two network calls that are executed in succession, let's call them Operation A and Operation B. I'm displaying a indeterminate progress bar saying something like "Performing Operation A" and "Performing Operation B". This is all fine.

Upon rotation, I'm trying to reconnect to the two potentially pending request, but not sure how to figure out what to display in my progress bar details. I can only detect misses, but not successful attachment to pending requests.

Any ideas on how to do that? If I use a generic message like "Loading..." in my progress bar, then I guess I could go with a synchronized reference counting type approach where I hide the progress bar if it ever gets to zero, but I was hoping there's an easier way. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, unfortunately I had to do exactly what I was describing using an AtomicInteger.

Comment: hah! I ended up do the same thing too!